# Hiding environment from closure

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

I was watching this video [Object-Oriented Programming is Bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM1iUe6IofM&t=41m10s). The subject is not really related to the question I'll ask, but the video leads to it. Precisely, at `41:10`, he speaks about a feature that doesn't seem to exist in python, he talks about the ability to have nested functions/blocks that are not aware of the complete local context but instead, are aware of some variables selected by hand. Basically, he asks for the ability to remove/partially hide environment from a closure.

Here is what the desired feature might look like in python (using a `use` decorator for example):

```py
def foo():
  x, y, z = 1, 2, 3

  def baz():
    print(x, y)  # prints "1 2"

  @use(y)
  def bar():
    print(y)  # Should print "2"
    z = 4     # Should create a local variable named `z`
    print(x)  # Should raise a NameError (`x` not defined)

  bar(), baz())

foo()
```

I've tried to implement that decorator but without success, so I tried with a simpler objective that is not to partially hide the environment but hiding it completely. Here is a solution I found:

```py
import ctypes

def foo():
  x, z = 1

  def baz():
    print(x)  # prints 1

  @hide_environment
  def bar(y):
    print(y)  # prints 2
    z = 3
    print(z)  # prints 3
    print(x)  # NameError is raised

  baz(), bar(2)

def hide_environment(f):
  def environment_agnostic_f(*args, **kwargs):
    remove_environment(f)
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  return environment_agnostic_f

def remove_environment(f):
  if f.__closure__ is None: 
    return
  for v in f.__closure__:
    py_obj = ctypes.py_object(v)
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyCell_Set(py_obj, None)  # that look like it could go wrong

foo()
```

I have four questions:

1. Does it already exist in python?
2. Is it possible to implement the `use` mechanism described in the video (within python)?
3. Is my implementation of `hide_environment` correct?

I don't see how 2. is possible as I have no idea if it is possible to intercept/or find the cell address at which `y`'s value has been placed. I'm not certain to understand how this is handled, but from what I understand, when `foo` is read, the "compiler" (not sure if one should really call it that way) puts all the `locals` from `foo` in `__closure__` objects that will later be referenced by `bar` and `baz`. This lead to my last question:

4. Is there anywhere in the documentation where the way closure are handled is described?

Comment: "Is there any way to have documentation on what is happening here?" seems like a very strange question. I'm not quite sure what you're asking there; perhaps you've given a literal translation of a phrasing that's common in your native language, but not in English.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the documentation where the way closure are handled is described?/Is there any way of knowing what is going on when the interpreter fills `__closure__`'s cells? In other words, what I'm NOT looking for is a link to a piece of documentation that describes what closure are or why they work the way they do on the user side. I'm looking for an implementation documentation that specifies how this is handled by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't come with Python, but the easiest way to implement it would be to just check what the function uses and throw an exception if it uses too much:

```
def allow_closure_vars(*okay_names):
    def checker(f):
        used_names = set(f.__code__.co_freevars)
        bad_names = used_names - set(okay_names)
        if bad_names:
            raise ValueError(f"Function uses the following variables it shouldn't: {bad_names}")
        return f
    return checker

def f():
    x, y = 1, 2
    @allow_closure_vars('x')
    def g():
        print(y)
    g()

f()
```

The attempt to define `g` will raise a `ValueError`.

Your implementation doesn't actually prohibit closure variable access. It just unassigns the variables, much like a `del` statement would. The function still has access to the variables, but they've been unassigned. This is likely to screw with the outer function, which probably wasn't expecting those variables to be unassigned, and it doesn't stop any code from assigning new values to the variables.

Comment: "The function still has access to the variables, but they've been unassigned" I'm not sure to understand the difference, what I understand is that I have access to an empty cell `<cell at ...: empty>` which raises `NameError: free variable 'x' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope` (which is basically what I wanted to have). 

"This is likely to screw with the outer function, which probably wasn't expecting those variables to be unassigned". Isn't the `__closure__` a local copy? If I modify the environment of `f`'s closure isn't that change only visible to/affecting `f`?

Comment: "and it doesn't stop any code from assigning new values to the variables." I'll update my question because I don't want to stop bar from being able to declare a local variable named `x` so this is not a problem. I'll try to play with you solution :)

Comment: @cglacet: `__closure__` isn't a local copy. You are essentially performing `del y` in the scope of `foo`.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a problem indeed, I added a `try/except` in `bar()` and called `baz()` second and it indeed raised the same `NameError`.

Comment: Anyway, I think your solution matches all the criteria I'm looking for

Comment: Hmm, actually there is a small issue, if I understand correctly, your code checks if `g`'s code contains a free variable (statically) and therefore if I surround `print(y)` with a try-except the error is not captured (because this check is done statically).

Comment: Do you think your solution could apply to the dynamic case?

Comment: @cglacet: Is your goal to have a local variable instead of a closure variable? Any assignment to the variable inside the inner function would cause the inner function to use a local variable, so the only case in which this would make a difference is if you try to have a function read from a local variable for which its body contains no assignments, which is almost certainly a bug.

Comment: The first goal is to have a nested function that acts as if it was declared outside the containing function. The second goal is to be able to see some parts of the closer, which is what you proposed here. I just wondered if it was possible to achieve the same thing at runtime. This is not made to be used in my code, this is a purely fictional need.

Comment: "to have a function read from a local variable for which its body contains no assignments, which is almost certainly a bug." I feel like deciding this statically is not safe (in the sense that you would raise the exception on some occurrences where the code is actually correct). I understand that my try-except example is far fetched and make no sense on its own, but that's probably not the only way to have a valid code that raises an exception.

Comment: @cglacet: I think we have different ideas about what "safe" is in this situation. Anyway, if you want your function to look for a global variable instead of a closure variable, `global` is the way to go. If you want your function to look for a local variable despite containing no assignments to that local variable, then I'm baffled at your desires, but you can do that by including a variable annotation for the variable.